# Getting multimple results from Ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Maybe this is a duplicate but I can not understand why mo code does not work. I am trying to get multiple results via Ajax/php.

This is from my php file:

```
$result11 = 'test1'
$result22 = 'test2';

echo json_encode(array("data1" => $result11, "data2" => $result22));
```

Ajax call:

```
$(document.body).on('submit','#sendmessage',function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/send.php",
        data: {par:par,kid:kid,ha:ha,sform:sform,editors:editors},
        cache: false,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(datax) {
            alert(datax.data1);
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

**Problem:**

When I submit a form, the page refreshes instead of sending ajax request.

At the same time this works but I can't get multiple results from Php file:

```
$(document.body).on('submit','#sendmessagex',function() {

    var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/send.php",
        data:str,    
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a preventDefault() call to your script

```
$(document.body).on('submit','#sendmessagex',function(event) {
//----------------------------------------------------^^^^^
    event.preventDefault();
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/send.php",
            data:str,    
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }

    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This code works without preventDefault. Does not work the first example with dataType:'json',

Comment: Did you also add the parameter `event` to the function call??? It wont work without that

Answer (score 0):

You have to use preventDefault() ofcourse to prevent page refresh. Then you can use the second code without datatype json. But in that case at first you have to parse the json like this way:

```
success: function(data){
var datax = JSON.parse(data);
//now you have object and can access like this: datax.data1, datax.data2
}
```

Incase you want to use first code, in php you have to set php header to define it as proper json output.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```